# getting maximum value for varchar column mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

i need to get the largest number in column "meta_value" while other column equals "utteranceId", and i get wrong value.

i tried to use the max function but i don't get the largest number.

the meta_value column is of type varchar, and there is more records in the table that are text, but the records of meta_key: "utteranceId" are all numbers.

table:

```
meta_id post_id meta_key    meta_value
    986     168 utteranceId          1
    987     169 utteranceId          2
    990     170 utteranceId          3
    993     171 utteranceId          4
    996     172 utteranceId          5
    999     173 utteranceId          6
   1002     174 utteranceId          7
   1005     175 utteranceId          8
   1008     176 utteranceId          9
   1011     177 utteranceId         10
```

the query i use:

```
SELECT post_id, max(meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta where meta_key = "utteranceId";
```

result:
168 9

i need to get:
177     10

i

Comment: If you expect post_id to be relevant to the max; you need to group by post_id; otherwise, you'll get _"post_id values I came across while looking at rows satisfying the WHERE condition"_.

Comment: i need more the biggest value of meta_value

Comment: Is meta_value a varchar? (that would make '9' > '10')

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson ohhh right its a varchar.. but i cant change it because its a wordpress table.

Comment: SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta ORDER BY meta_value+0 DESC LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle varchar as number:

```sql
SELECT MAX(CONVERT(meta_value, SIGNED)) FROM wp_postmeta where meta_key = "utteranceId";
```

To select the corresponding post_id:

```sql
SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE CONVERT(meta_value, SIGNED) = (
    SELECT MAX(CONVERT(meta_value, SIGNED))
    FROM wp_postmeta 
    WHERE meta_key = "utteranceId" )
AND meta_key = "utteranceId";
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using nested query?

```
SELECT post_id, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta where meta_value = (SELECT 
max(CAST(meta_value AS INT))FROM wp_postmeta where meta_key = "utteranceId");
```